# Error: “Windows failed to start. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.”

Tags: windows-7, boot

"The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible"

I am not able to change change settings in bios because admin password is set and I do not 
have the password. I did set the HDD password and know that. I am able to access F8 but the `Repair My Computer` option is not working. F10 is available as well and reads:

```
Edit boot optios for: Windows 7
Path: \Windows system32\winload.exe

Partion: 1
Hard Disk: d7a5bd9d

[ /NOEXECUTE=OPTIN ]
```

I have access to F2 and F12 but cannot change settings because I do not have the BIOS password. I have access to F10 which reads what I have included above and am able to change [NO EXECUTE=OPTIN] and then the system boots to where it says `Starting Windows` and then windows colors for windows logo begin to form and stops boot and restarts process all over again. Boot options available to me are "Hard Drive" USB Storage Device, CD/DVD/CD-RW Device, Network, Diagnostics, and Enter Setup. I have run setup and all test come back as passing.

I have 2 computers that are in this current state. A Dell M5010 (A15) as well as a Sony Vaio model PCG-71312L. I do not have recovery discs for either, nor a Windows 7 CD. I do have a recovery option for windows on a SD card, but neither is recognizing it. Is there a way to transfer recovery from a working computer to either of these units?

Comment: If you don't have access to the BIOS then you are stuck. You will need to reset the BIOS password to resolve this problem.  You also need access to a Windows 7 disk to solve this.

Comment: @ramhound If he has access to F2 or F12 (meaning he is able to choose a boot device) he doesn't need to reset BIOS pw IMHO. DVD is necessary though

Answer (score 1):

While this may not answer your question, it will surely point you in the right direction.

You should reset the BIOS by using one of these tools.

**Note that these programs have no warranty. Use at your own risk.**

[**Dell Bios Editor**](http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/19369-Dell-Bios-Editing-Removing-Bios-Lock-Changing-Service-Asset-Tag-Software-Here?p=278250&viewfull=1#post278250)

[**PC CMOS Cleaner**](http://www.pccmos.com/product.html)

You should also check out http://www.tech-faq.com/reset-bios-password.html This site has a lot of technical information on CMOS and BIOS reset.

Quote from http://www.tech-faq.com/reset-dell-bios-password.html

> Each Dell Inspiron has a master password that clears the BIOS
>   password. Call Dell Technical Support at (800)624-9896 to get this
>   number.
>
> Dell Technical Support will request the Service Tag and Express
>   Service Code from the bottom of the Inspiron.
>
> If the current user is not the original Inspiron owner, Dell will
>   transfer the used Inspiron’s registration from the original owner with
>   only the Service Tag and Express Service Code from the tag on the
>   laptop.
>
> To transfer a used Dell Inspiron’s registration, fill out the [Transfer
>   of Ownership form](http://www.dell.com/support/retail/us/en/19/ownershiptransfer/IdentifySystem)  on Dell’s web site.

Comment: Also many BIOSes have "secret" passwords for field maintenance (and Google knows all about them, obviously ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I had this error happening when I switch physical disk. E.g. restored backup copy of a partition to another (bigger) disk. Original disk was unavailable (hence the error). This might not be the only cause, but how do you remedy it:
One way is to use BCD Edit or any other program that does editing windows boot manager files. I just found an article on this very site so please [read it](https://superuser.com/questions/469793/the-boot-selection-failed-because-a-required-device-is-inaccessible-0xc000000e). If it helps - upvote it's response and - for future reference - use search box on top of this page before asking a question ;]

Oh and windows 7 DVD might be downloadable off MS site, if you use it only for recovery purpose i don't think they will mind. [go there](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/cc442495.aspx) and see if they let you. Or just borrow from someone.