# Windows 7 - bcdedit shows device and osdevice = unknown

Tags: windows-7, boot, bcdedit

I recently added a new 2 TB drive to my desktop, and reordered how SATA cables were plugged into my motherboard for my other 3 disks (moving some to SATA 6 gb/s port on motherboard etc).  This new drive was just an additional storage drive, the original OS/boot device was still in place, only the SATA port was changed.

I had some issues booting afterwards.  Windows would get to loading screen and just spin and spin.  I left it for over 24 hours with no changes.  I ended up using a Windows 7 dvd and using recovery options.  It found a previous system restore point and restored it.  After this I was able to boot again.

However, when I go to command prompt and run `bcdedit` this is my output:

```
 C:\Users\Administrator>bcdedit

 Windows Boot Manager
 --------------------
 identifier              {bootmgr}
 device                  unknown
 description             Windows Boot Manager
 locale                  en-US
 inherit                 {globalsettings}
 default                 {current}
 resumeobject            {d9491a3a-d7dc-11dd-8382-b9347c3c15cd}
 displayorder            {current}
 toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
 timeout                 5

 Windows Boot Loader
 -------------------
 identifier              {current}
 device                  unknown
 path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
 description             Windows 7
 locale                  en-US
 inherit                 {bootloadersettings}
 osdevice                unknown
 systemroot              \Windows
 resumeobject            {d9491a3a-d7dc-11dd-8382-b9347c3c15cd}
 nx                      OptIn`
```

I am curious why it shows `device = unknown` and `osdevice = unknown` for the {current} boot entry?  Is this a problem?  Can it be fixed manually?

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible 0xc000000e](https://superuser.com/questions/469793/the-boot-selection-failed-because-a-required-device-is-inaccessible-0xc000000e)